# Run Word Macro from Ribbon in Visual Studio

Tags: vba, vb.net, ms-word, ribbon

I am trying to create a button in a custom ribbon for Word built in VSTO to run a macro in what will be the open Word doc. The Word doc already has the macro so I really would not like to rewrite the macro in VSTO, just want to run the existing one.

This is my best guest from reading other sources but I know I am missing something:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim oWord As Word.ApplicationClass
        oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        oWord.Run("SampleMacro")
    End Sub
```

I know very little about VSTO and VB so the more details the better! Thank you.

Comment: Ha, thanks for that. Unfortunately no new results to read through.